# Dart jsonDecode fails to parse complex json string

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

When I try to parse the following JSON string, the `jsonDecode` does not parse it correctly.

```
var json = '{"errors":[{"code":"INVALID_USER_PASSWORD","status":401,"title":"Invalid user name or password"}]}';

final parsedJson = jsonDecode(json);
```

Output
[image]

any help is appreciated.

Edited:
Screenshot Shot 2
[image]

Answer (score 1):

"errors" is an array of objects and contains only one object.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  
  var json = '{"errors":[{"code":"INVALID_USER_PASSWORD","status":401,"title":"Invalid user name or password"}]}';

  final Map map = jsonDecode(json);
  
  String title = map['errors'][0]['title'];
  String code = map['errors'][0]['code'];
  int status = map['errors'][0]['status'];
  
  print(title);
  print(code);
  print(status);
}
```

Comment: Yes, technically it should work like this, But if you pay attention to the screenshot I have attached to the question, the `errors` field is just a string in a `List`, nothing else is there.

Comment: you need to click the 3rd arrow to reveal the contents.

Comment: In addition, your sample json only contains one (1) error, so that's all you will see.

Comment: Please see my 2nd screenshot which I just added in the question

Comment: The response from calling your API is failing, that's an entirely different issue from `jsonDecode` not being able to parse the string. If you run the code from @VivekChib, you will see that the values are printed properly. Therefore, `jsonDecode` is working.